# Rails3 sunspot has_many assoctiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have trouble with searching with the sunspot gem. I want to search for user email in an object tenant.

tenant has many users

In the tenant I did this:

```
searchable do
  text :name, :notifications_email

  text :users do  
    users.map(&:email)  
  end
end
```

Searching for the `name` and `notifications_email` works fine, but when I search for an email of the user no result is found.

I did this in the console:

```
s = Tenant.solr_search do fulltext "info" end
```

I get this object:

```
<Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:Tenant"], :q=>"info", :fl=>"* score", :qf=>"name_text   notifications_email_text users_text", :defType=>"dismax", :start=>0, :rows=>30}>
```

What confuses me is that there is `users_text` doesn't it have to be `users_email_text` or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it more clear, you should define your searchable block like:

```
searchable do
  text :name
  text :notifications_email
  text :users_email do  
    users.map(&:email)
  end  
end
```

During index time, Sunspot appends the type of the attribute to the end of name of the attribute. In the case of `:users_email`, it gets turned into `qf=>users_email_text`. It seems like your confusion is around the naming conventions. I could have defined the email attribute to anything I wanted, as long as I defined what it contained in the `do` block. Defining it like this:

```
searchable do
  text :name
  text :notifications_email
  text :emails do  
    users.map(&:email)
  end  
end
```

Would have given me the same functionality, just Sunspot would turn the variable name into `qf=>emails_text` durning index time.